# Is it possible to Monitor a Vaadin Application With Nagios?

Tags: monitoring, vaadin, nagios

I have a Vaadin Application and would like to monitor it with Nagios. That means checking if the application is running and perform an automated login to see if the database and application are working "together". The login page itself is not a static component. Its part of the application.

I tried using the WebInject plugin but it didn't work. The Request Body looks like the following.

```
f940dc7b-4826-462e-9681-20f26ac18303[['0','com.vaadin.shared.ui.ui.UIServerRpc','resize',['949','1680','1680','949']],['9','v','v',['text',['s','test']]],['9','v','v',['c',['i','7']]],['10','v','v',['text',['s','test']]],['10','v','v',['c',['i','12']]]]"
```

I guess the problem is that its an application and not just a static website with a simple post login. Is it even possible to check it properly with Nagios? Maybe my approach is not the right one?

Comment: It could prove tricky.... Why not just setup a normal servlet and check against this one? You could then include more information in the servlet response...

Comment: You could write an own Nagios plugin (which in its simplest form can just be a batch script) and use PhantomJS as a headless browser to perform the login. If this succeeds, the Nagios check script only needs to exit with code 0, otherwise 1 or 2 (warning or critical).